# Search Array list case insensitive

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public void setSpeciality(String spec) {
    if(specialities.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.equalsIgnoreCase(spec))) {
        speciality =spec;
    }
    else
    speciality = "General Practitioner";
}
```

I need to search an array list called specialities (case insensitive) ^ see my attempt at an answer^ but cant figure out what in my answer is wrong.

Comment: Easiest way, if you don't care about the case of the data returned, is to just store lowercase strings in your list, and then compare the input, lowercased, using `List#contains`.  See the duplicate link for a Java 8 solution as well.

Comment: You need to add an else block and move `speciality = "General Practitioner";` into it

Comment: Also, what  result are you expecting? What result are you getting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't the dupe target is correct. The OP understands how to check if an element is in the list case insensitively. OP's problem is _getting_ the element that matches the predicate.

Comment: Your method will always set `speciality` to "General Practitioner" no matter if the `if` statement is true or not. Looks like you are missing the `else` part of your `if` statment.

Comment: @JustSomeDude else statement didnt fix it

Comment: @HughM how is your answer wrong? can you explain what the output is that you are calling wrong?

Comment: @HughM check your input parameter that you are passing in setSpeciality method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`anyMatch` only returns `true` or `false` indicating whether there is at least 1 element in the stream that satisfies the predicate.

You should use `filter` and `findFirst`, which returns the first element that matches the predicate:

```
speciality = specialities.stream()
                 .filter(spec::equalsIgnoreCase)
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse("General Practitioner");
```

Comment: Its giving me the error "cannot convert from Stream<String> to String"

Comment: @TheScientificMethod According to the comments in OP's code, `speciality` should have the value of an element in the list, not `spec`.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Let's say `spec` is "ONCOLOGIST" and the list contains "Oncologist", `speciality` should be `"Oncologist"` after the method is called.

Comment: @Sweeper i got your point, but he can do it like `speciality =spec.toLowerCase();`

Comment: @TheScientificMethod How can you be sure that the string in the list is all lowercase?

Comment: @HughM You are not allowed to edit what? `specialities` is a `List<String>` right? Then it should work. You should replace your whole method body with the code snippet.

Comment: @Sweeper I figured it out based on your response! Thanks

Comment: Since `String.equalsIgnoreCase` is symmetric we could also write the filter using a method reference: `.filter(spec::equalsIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 0):

just include, `speciality =spec.toLowerCase();` and convert the first character to uppercase

```
public void setSpeciality(String spec) {
    if(specialities.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.equalsIgnoreCase(spec))) {
        speciality =spec.toLowerCase();
        speciality = String.valueOf((speciality.charAt(0)).toUpperCase())  + speciality.substring(1) ;
    }
    else {
          speciality = "General Practitioner";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are overriding speciality so every time you will be getting same result.

change code like below

```
    public void setSpeciality(String spec) {
       if(specialities.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.equalsIgnoreCase(spec))) {
            speciality =spec;
       }else{
           speciality = "General Practitioner";
       }
     }
```

Comment: There is still the issue of AnyMatch which as @Sweeper showed it only indicates true or false

Comment: Of course. All this answer did, it put the assignment expression in a statement.